# Linking 2 data frames and returning a value using lookup

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm a beginner in coding and data in general so any help I can get would be really helpful.

If I have a data frame as below,where every matchup is a tuple.

```
df1 = Team A Player 1.1        Team A Player 2.1              Team A Player 3.1
     ('Max', 'Hatteberg')   ('Hatteberg', 'Tejada')            ('Max', 'Rincon')
     ('Tejada', 'Brown')    ('Hatteberg', 'Rincon')         ('Hatteberg','Brown')
```

and so on..

and I have a crosstable:

```
df2 =         Max  Hatteberg  Tejada     Brown     Rincon

  Max         NaN    -1.0      +2.0      -8.0       +5.0

  Hatteberg  +1.0     NaN      +2.5      +3.0         0

  Tejada     -2.0    -2.5       NaN      +5.5       -3.5

  Brown      +8.0    -3.0      -5.5       NaN       +2.8

  Rincon     -5.0      0       +3.5       2.8        NaN
```

And I wanted for each matchup to return a value as so

```
df1 = matchups 1    matchups 2    matchups 3
        +1.0           -2.5         -5.0
        -5.5             0          -3.0
```

I've tried,

```
df1.applymap(lambda x : df2.lookup([x[0]],[x[1]])[0])
```

But it returned,

```
('One or more row labels was not found', 'occurred at index Team A Player 1.1')
```

I'm having issues referencing to both of the data frames and returning a value. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is more like you have some value in df1 tuples refer to None value from df2

You can do with `reindex` before `apply` `lookup`

```
name=set(list(itertools.chain(*list(itertools.chain(*df1.values.tolist())))))
df2=df2.reindex(name).reindex(name,axis=1)
df1.applymap(lambda x : df2.lookup([x[0]],[x[1]])[0])
```

Comment: Do I need to define `name` for anything? Sorry, trying to learn but I'm terrible at it